# SharePoint Subsite won't allow Inheritance of site master page from parent of this site

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, master-page, html

One issue I am trying to solve on my SharePoint site has to do with the Master Page itself, especially on the main site (domain.sharepoint.com).

The master page contains headers (some single, some are dropdown selections) that lead to different sites/collections. When a header is updated on that master page, it does not update on the other sites, instead I have to go in 1 by 1 to update the header in the master page and it is a pain in the arse. Instead I would like to have all of the headers update at once in the master page.

Everything I have looked into:

- Site Master Page Settings (Inherit site master page from parent of this site(on subsite, but will not allow me to choose this selection it is greyed out))
- This [site](https://praveensharepointknowledgebase.wordpress.com/2018/03/05/change-sub-site-master-page-without-enabling-publishing-feature/), enter https:///_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx but access is denied
- And this [site](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/93cb27/change-the-master-page-to-site-in-sharepoint-2013-online/), which will not allow me to do the same thing as I mentioned in the first bullet.

I am not sure if these are even fixes to my issue, but it was the only thing I came across even closely related to it.

If anyone knows this issue I am having or where to point me, that would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the site template you are using and what is your permission on this site?

Add your account to the **Site Collection Administrator** list to begin with.

Also, I have run a bunch of tests and found out that **publishing features** are required to actually update the Site Master Page Settings.

The settings can be accessed well (no greyed out) but will return `unexpected error` when clicking *OK*. But with publishing features activated, they can be saved without error.